# Sql query that will alphabetize my return except on a certain data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm struggling on how to query to put my data on combobox, which I need to alphabetize. But I need to put certain data on top.

Example: `mango`, `apple`, `banana` etc. After `mango` I need to put the other data in alphabetical order.

I don't have codes yet but my field for that is `loc_city`.

I'm doing this in PHP.

Comment: Some more effort, please. Sample data, your current query and wanted result is a good start!

Comment: You can have a effort on that using two queries, and getting inner query value withing the outer query result set. It is very hard to give a good and relevant answer without have some code.

Comment: wait i will upload it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following syntax:-

```
SELECT YOUR_COLS
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE CONDS.
ORDER BY CASE WHEN NAME = 'Mango' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END;
```

Comment: Should there also be a `, NAME ASC` to get something like `mango, apple, banana`? `ORDER BY (CASE WHEN NAME = 'Mango' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END), NAME ASC;`

Comment: I dont think ASC is needed as Case statement will solely do the trick.

Comment: Ok, the `ASC` is not necessary, but we should also order by `NAME` in the second level to solve this part of @Brian s question: `after that mango i need to put the other data in alphabetical order`?

Comment: That is also not needed. Because case statement consist of Name cloumn that will solve the purpose.

Comment: I don't understand... `NAME` is only used for getting `1` or `2`. For all NAMEs != `Mango` (e.g. `Orange`, `Banana`, `Apple`) the value `2` will be used for sorting. How does your statement make sure, that the values resulting in `2` have to be sorted alphametically so that the result will be `Mango, Apple, Banana, Orange`?

Comment: 1 and 2 are the order to be used for sorting. When name matches with mango it will sort that first and later every value wil be sorted by name in tarditional way. Now i think you got your answer.